# Caching with single-page application

Tags: single-page-application, browser-cache, sapui5, cache-manifest, manifest.cache

I have an OpenUI5 app; my app have only one htlm page (index.html), some js file (for the logic-controller) and some xml file (for the view).

The app is a single-page application; this is my `index.html` start page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="app.appcache">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />-->

    <title>My App</title>

    <!-- UI5 Bootstrap with OpenUI5 -->
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"

            type="text/javascript"
            src="resources/openui/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "ui5bp": "./",
            "model": "./model"
             }'
        >
    </script>



    <!-- Custom Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

   <script>

        new sap.m.Shell("Shell", {
            showLogout : false,
            app : new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                name : 'ui5bp'
            }),
            homeIcon : {
                'phone' : "img/57_ogo.jpg",
                'phone@2' : "img/114_logo.jpg",
                'tablet' : "img/72__logo.jpg",
                'tablet@2' : "img/144_logo.jpg",
                'precomposed': false,
                'favicon' : "img/favicon.ico"
            }
        }).placeAt('root');
   </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="root">
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my **manifest** file `app.appcache` (I change it at each new version)

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#APP VERSION 1.0.4-rc4

#insert here files to cache

#insert here files to NOT cache
NETWORK:
*
```

OK! But now I copy the app on my server and BOOM! some page are reloaded but others do not... (for example I have a login XML-view where I show the release version which is updated and a XML for a setting dialog which is not updated)
Why I have this behavior? I would like that the browser reload each file at each reloading

P.S. 
If I reload manaully the app by F5 the problem remains.
If I add on the index.html file these meta-tag the problems remains

```html
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

The only mode to force the reloading of the whole app by the browser is cancel the cache manually:

[image]

Comment: What is the question again? You are talking about browser refresh using F5. If the app cache is done as expected, a F5 refresh should NOT fetch new versions from the server. That is the point of the app cache!

Comment: When I'm testing, I usually open the chrome console and tick the `disable cache` box in the Network tab

Comment: maybe I have found the problem.. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache#Example_1_a_simple_cache_manifest_file) 
The red message says: "Important: Do not specify the manifest itself in the cache manifest file, otherwise it will be nearly impossible to inform the browser a new manifest is available."
Maybe in the past I have inserted appcache file into appcache... O_o

Answer (score 0):

If you can include Java Servlet Filter in your SPA, here is a working solution: [CorrectBrowserCacheHandlerFilter.java](https://gist.github.com/anthony-o/1b415e2e134f33cdb637d3cad97a265c)

Basically, when your browser requests the static files, the server will redirect every requests to the same one but with a hash query parameter (`?v=azErT` for example) which depends on the content of the target static file.

Doing this, the browser will never cache the static files declared in your `index.html`for example (because will always received a `302 Moved Temporarily`), but will only cache the ones with the hash version (the server will answer `200` for them). So the browser cache will be used efficiently for those static files with hash version.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `CorrectBrowserCacheHandlerFilter.java`.